# confusion about universal reference. In my code f(T&&...) compiler error but f(T...) succeed

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference

My workspace is in Windows, Visual Studio 2017. I write two templates to change all str-like to std::wstring. But a complier err comes:

```
Error   C2975   
'_Test': invalid template argument for 'std::conditional', expected compile-time constant expression
```

My code is following:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>

std::wstring to_wide_string(const std::string& input)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > converter;
    return converter.from_bytes(input);
}

std::string to_byte_string(const std::wstring& input)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > converter;
    return converter.to_bytes(input);
}


// a template to check if the Args can be used in F's constructors.
// for example , check<std::string>(3, 'a').value == true
template <class F>
struct check
{
    template <class... Args>
    constexpr check(Args&&... args) : value(
        std::is_void<
            decltype(t2<F, Args...>(0, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
        >::type::value) {}

    bool value;

    struct nat {};
    template <class G, class... GArgs>
    static auto t2(int, GArgs&&... args) -> decltype(G(std::forward<GArgs>(args)...), void());
    template <class, class...>
    static auto t2(...)->nat;
};

// this template is make all wstr-like to std::string. But I don't finish it yet
template <typename T, bool is_wstring = std::is_same<std::wstring, std::decay_t<T>>::value>
struct to_tstring : std::string
{
};

// I want all str-like can be translated to std::wstring
template <typename T>
struct to_tstring<T, true> : std::wstring
{
    template <typename... Args>
    // if I change Args&&... to Args..., it will compile succeed
    to_tstring(Args&&... args) : to_tstring<T, true>(
        std::conditional<
            check<std::string>(std::forward<Args>(args)...).value,
            std::true_type, std::false_type
        >::type(),
        std::forward<Args>(args)...
        ) 
    {
        std::cout << "to_tstring<T, true>::ctor_1" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    template <typename... Args>
    to_tstring(std::false_type, Args&&... args) : std::wstring(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
        std::cout << "to_tstring<T, true>::ctor_2 false_type" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    to_tstring(std::true_type, Args&&... args) : std::wstring(to_wide_string(std::string(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) {
        std::cout << "to_tstring<T, true>::ctor_3 true_type" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    to_tstring<std::wstring> a("asdf"); // compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why the **std::conditional** does not recognize the **checkstd::string(std::forward(args)...).value**. It's fine to be a constexpr when I used it in main:

```
int main()
{
   constexpr int i = check<std::string>(3,'j').value;
   int s[i] = {};   // it's fine
}
```

By coincidence, I change the signature from **to_tstring(Args&&... args)** to **to_tstring(Args... args)**, now it is successful to complie. But I don't know why.

The reason I need those template, it's I have a macro called TSTRING. TSTIRNG is std::string in WIN32, std::wstring in x64. Sometimes std::string and std::wstring can be showed at same time, so I want to tranform all the string I meeted to TSTRING

Comment: please post a [mcve]. You cannot specialize `to_tstring` before declaring a primary template.

Comment: Nothing stops you from using wstring on 32-bit Windows. `TCHAR` & Co was once good for Windows 95, but not useful anymore.

Comment: It's a bad idea to extend `std::string`. Consider creating a factory functor/function that returns `std::string` instead.